# About clickhouse to aggreate data from table1，2，3 to tableALL？

Tags: clickhouse

I have a table in ClickHouse, where the columns of TABLE1 are DT, CUST_ID, and ONE, and TABLE2 has columns DT, CUST_ID, and TWO, and so on. DT represents time partition, CUST_ID serves as the unique primary key, while ONE, TWO, THREE... FIFTY represent numerical values. Currently, I have 50 tables like this, ranging from Table1 to Table50. I would like to aggregate them into one table, with columns DT, CUST_ID, ONE, TWO, THREE... FIFTY.
table DDL LIKE THIS:
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(
'DT' DATE,
'CUST_ID' STRING,
'ONE',
)ENGINE = MERGEETREE();
CREATE TABLE TABLE2(
'DT' DATE,
'CUST_ID' STRING,
'TWO',
)ENGINE = MERGEETREE();

I WANDER A TABLE LIKE THIS
CREATE TABLE TABLE_ALL(
'DT' DATE,
'CUST_ID' STRING,
'ONE',
'TWO',
...
'FIFTY'
)ENGINE = MERGEETREE();
clickhouse version：21.9
and table engine:mergeeTree()
and if i use join table.the memory is oversize.
if somebody can help me?3Q~

Can somebody give me solution?
i use to try chatgpt .but union all and insert step by step is not enough.